Minimum size of a synchrotron required to get desired wavelength?
Synchrotrons are regularly used to generate various wavelengths of light. I get that there is a tradeoff between electron energy and bending radius/angle required to obtain a given wl. (For example, https://www.nist.gov/pml/sensor-science/what-synchrotron-radiation has a nice concise summary.) What that summary doesn't tell me is how big (or small) the ring has to be to get to that energy and bending radius. So, for example, suppose I wanted visible light, say 500nm just to pick a random wl, and I want it to be as small as possible and as low energy as possible. Optimizing Eq. 1 from the above-linked page is possible, but seems difficult. (Actually, since it's an integral, just not bothering with the integration and setting the equation -- which is the derivative of the integral -- sans integral, =0 maybe be a way to find a maximum rather easily.) Is there some direct commonplace equation that synchrotron engineers do these computations?

be careful with viewing the integrand as the derivative of the integral when dealing with definitive integrals, like this one

Right. Good point. Let me ask this more simply: Can I build a synchrotron in my garage that creates visible light? VIS is much lower energy (longer wl) than DUV/X, so should require orders of magnitude less power. I'm more academically interested in size and power calculations than actually building one...because, of course, I'm not really going to...duh! :-) My intuition from these equations is that in order to bend it enough to fit into a large garage (say dia=10 m) and still get vis light, I need to power it down quite a bit (otherwise the bending would generate DUV/X)
